# Vim lines get off-by-one

Tags: xubuntu, vim

On Xubuntu 13.04, when I execute a VIM command command mode, like [esc] then `:w`. I'll occasionally find that a bunch of gobbly-gook stays in the very last line of the terminal. The text with the results of the command, ie

```
"test.txt" 6L, 36C written                 6,1 Bot
```

Will now appear on the second-to-last line of Vim instead of the very last line.

The problem is, when I'm returned to insert mode, the display is now one line off from what I'm editing. This only becomes apparent as I edit each character one-by-one. I'm not editing what is being displayed, and somehow everything is shifted up one line.

So somehow the Vim display buffer is getting corrupted, **as if the EOL I type at the end of the command is not getting dealt with by vim** (or the console?). As if the shell executes the EOL to scroll everything up a line when it shouldn't be, and now vim/the console is in a rather inconsistent state.

The only recourse is to restart vim.

Relevant versions:

```
vim 7.3.547
xfce-terminal 0.6.1
```

Comment: Using bash too?

Comment: Yes, using bash.

Comment: Does use `ctrl-l` to redraw help? are you still experiencing this?